# get status_code for http.urlopen

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, urllib2, urllib3

How can I print the status code for this response? (eg 200/401 etc)

```
resp = http.urlopen('POST', 'https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/6789oh', headers=headers, body=json.dumps(data))
print(str(resp.data))
```

I tried:

```
resp.code
resp.get_code()
```

etc but none of them work for `http.urlopen`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use urllib.request , try this see if it helps

import urllib.request , json

try:

```
resp=urllib.request.urlopen('POST','https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/6789oh',headers=headers, body=json.dump(data))
```

except urllib.error.URLError as a :

```
print(str(a.status) +"\n" + str(a.message))
```

except urllib.error.URLError as e :

```
print(str(e.code) +"\n"+ str(e.msg))
```